# do while true case with only the given character

Tags: bash, do-while

I need a script which adds some information to my server after starting the script.
It needs to input the IP address but I also want it to send me an error message if I did not input the IP in the correct form.

What I tried:

```
while true ; do
   read -p "which IP did the Location used? in this form xx.xx.xx" newip
   case $newip in
       [0123456789.]* )echo "success";break;;
       * ) echo "only input in this Form xx.xx.xx";;
   esac
done
```

What I wanted:

```
which IP did the Location use? in this form xx.xx.xx
input: 10.10.10
output: success

which IP did the Location use? in this form xx.xx.xx
input: 10-10.10
output: only input in this Form xx.xx.xx

which IP did the Location use? in this form xx.xx.xx
input: 10.10.10
output: success
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to `case`, you can exclude the parts which are wrong, to focus on those which are correct.

```
while true ; do
   read -p "Which IP did the location use? In this form xx.xx.xx.xx " newip
   case $newip in
       *[^0-9.]* | *.*.*.*.* ) ;;
       *.*.*.* ) echo "success"; break ;;
       * ) ;;
   esac
   echo "only input in this Form xx.xx.xx.xx" >&2
done
```

Real IP addresses have four octets; if you genuinely want only three, it should hopefully be obvious how to change this.

Perhaps also notice the addition of a space at the end of the `read -p` prompt (as well as some minor English fixes).

Answer (score 0):

In a glob, `*` matches **any** character.

Bash does have regex support using `=~`. For example:

```
if [[ $newip =~ ^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
    echo ok
else
    echo bad
fi
```